# It doesn't seem that Watir.default_timeout works when I use it in my rspec test

Tags: rspec, watir

I need to expand the duration of the wait on the **@page.run_asset** because it could take longer than 30secs for the process to complete.  So I found Watir.default_time and added it to my code.  When I run the test it still fails and displays the same error as before:

> Failure/Error: @page.run_asset
>        Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ScriptTimeOutError:
>          script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds

```
it 'expects table action to succeed' do
  Watir.default_timeout = 180
  @page.debug_asset(table_name)
  @page.select_sample(sample)
  @page.run_asset
  expect(@page.return_to_input_element.present?).to be true
end
```

I tried implementing the following code and it displayed the same error.

```
it 'expects table action to succeed' do
  wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 150)
  @page.debug_asset(table_name)
  @page.run_asset
  field_displayed = wait.until { 
  @asset_debugger_page.return_to_input_element.present? }
  expect(@page.return_to_input_element.present?).to be true
end
```

I've looked around and can not seem to find the a good answer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Watir timeout is for how long Watir will wait for an element to show up or become, present, not how long to wait for page loads, script execution, or network reads. You want to set a [script timeout](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#timeouts) in capabilities.

This is how you increase script timeout in Watir:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, timeouts: {script: 60000})
```

Comment: What is the max of the script timeout?

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work successfully.

@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, timeouts: { script: 60_000 }, options: @opts)

This is how I have implemented the suggestion in my code and it is still timing out in 30 seconds.  Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is more information on the error I am seeing.

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ScriptTimeOutError:
       script timeout: result was not received in 30 seconds
         (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.119)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059 (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

I have looked and looked and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to my code and it is working now.

browser.driver.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 150_000

An issue has been logged for the Watir solution.

Thank you for your help.